# Google sheets transfer data with matching rows

Tags: python, google-sheets

I'm trying to transfer data between two sheets by matching firstName but leaving the header in place.

I have it almost correct but the last line of matching rows is being duplicated in the output.  here is the relevant code:

I've tried several different things but nothing that is quite right yet:

```
# Get the source and target sheet data
    try:
        source_range = f"{sheet1_name}!A:B"
        source_data = sheets_api.values().get(spreadsheetId=sheet_id, range=source_range).execute().get('values', [])

        target_range = f"{sheet2_name}!A:B"
        target_data = sheets_api.values().get(spreadsheetId=sheet_id, range=target_range).execute().get('values', [])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: Failed to retrieve data from Google Sheets - {str(e)}")
        return 4  # Error code 4

    # Convert data to DataFrames considering only firstName and email columns
    source_df = pd.DataFrame(source_data, columns=['firstName', 'email'])
    target_df = pd.DataFrame(target_data, columns=target_data[0])

    # Alphabetize names in source sheet
    source_df = source_df.sort_values(by='firstName')

    # Alphabetize names in target sheet
    target_df = target_df.sort_values(by='firstName')

   # Find matching first names between source sheet and target sheet
    matched_rows = source_df[source_df['firstName'].isin(target_df['firstName'])].copy()

    # Exclude the row where firstName is "firstName" from matched names
    matched_rows = matched_rows[matched_rows['firstName'] != 'firstName']

   # Find the index of the row with firstName as "firstName" in the target sheet
    exclude_row_index = target_df[target_df['firstName'] == 'firstName'].index

    # Exclude the row from the target sheet
    target_df = target_df[~target_df.index.isin(exclude_row_index)]

    # Ignore "firstName" row in the source sheet
    source_df = source_df[source_df['firstName'] != 'firstName']

    # Remove matched rows from source sheet
    source_df = source_df[~source_df['firstName'].isin(target_df['firstName'])]

    # Clear the source sheet before updating
    clear_body = {
        'ranges': [source_range],
    }
    try:
        sheets_api.values().batchClear(spreadsheetId=sheet_id, body=clear_body).execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: Failed to clear source sheet - {str(e)}")
        return 5  # Error code 5
    
   # Update the target sheet with the matched rows
    for _, row in matched_rows.iterrows():
        target_row = target_df[target_df['firstName'] == row['firstName']].index[0]
        target_df.loc[target_row, 'email'] = row['email']

    # Exclude the row where firstName is "firstName" from matched names
    matched_rows = matched_rows[matched_rows['firstName'] != 'firstName']

    # Prepare the data to update the target sheet
    target_data = [target_df.columns.tolist()] + target_df.values.tolist()

    # Prepare the value range body for the API call
    value_range_body = {
        'values': target_data
    }

    # Update the target sheet with the modified data
    try:
        request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId=sheet_id,
            range=target_range,
            valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
            body=value_range_body
        )
        response = request.execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: Failed to update target sheet - {str(e)}")
        return 6  # Error code 6


    # Update the source sheet with the unmatched names
    try:
        source_body = {
            'values': [source_df.columns.tolist()] + source_df.values.tolist()
        }
        sheets_api.values().update(spreadsheetId=sheet_id, range=source_range, valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=source_body).execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: Failed to update source sheet - {str(e)}")
        return 7  # Error code 7

    return matched_rows  # Return matched rows
```

I've tried several things and get random output but mostly the fifth row is always D and is duplicated at times or else inserted if it's not there already.

I keep getting a duplicated row from the last row in the matching row data frame that is copied to the target sheet.

I expect this:

```
firstName   email
A   W
B   W
C   WW
D   W
TEST TEST
```

but get this:

```
firstName   email
A   W
B   W
C   WW
D   W
D   TEST
TEST    TEST
```

I also changed it to words and got this:

```
firstName   email
AN  W
BO  W
CAT W
D   
DOG 
EEL W
FAT W
GOD W
HIM W
IT  W
TEST    TEST
```

D row 5 was not on either sheet.

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.